# Lumen php artisan config:cache not found

Tags: laravel, caching, config, laravel-artisan, lumen

I'm trying out the PHP micro Framework Lumen (from laravel).
When I  set up Lumen and I try to use the `php artisan config:cache` command like in Laravel, I get this error :

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace.

So I have problem when I try to deploy the files to server, so I have to change `.env` file to change the database username and password.

This makes me think `config` is not available in artisan

How can I add it to artisan ?

Comment: Try to run `php artisan` to show `all` artisan commands. Then you can see.

Comment: when i run `php artisan` i can't find `config`  !!
is there any way to add it to `artisan `

Comment: Nope hehe. It only appears only Laravel :)

Comment: thanks for your response, i think we need to tell Taylor Otwell to add it in the future

Comment: @AhmedAlBermawy the only way is to install these command packages yourself for Lumen. It was stripped down for a reason and Taylor won't add these commands to Lumen.

Comment: @BhargavNanekalva You could use the [Lumen Generator](https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator) package

Comment: @ZeroThe2nd thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can not use the php artisan config:cache with your Lumen project, because it is not available out of the box.

You can add it by adding [this package (orumad/lumen-config-cache)](https://packagist.org/packages/orumad/lumen-config-cache) to your project:

```
composer require orumad/lumen-config-cache
```

Comment: may be i will check it later :)

Comment: How do you mean? What specific error do you see?
You can try other similar projects like this https://packagist.org/packages/niellles/lumen-commands

Comment: This package is not a replacement for `php artisan config:cache` it is useless if the config files are not written and used by you because it provides extra custom functions for getting the information.NOT VERY USEFUL THEREFORE!

Answer (score 3):

In `lumen` you have to add this configuration in `bootstrap/app.php` file

```
$app->configure('custom_config_file_name');

#example
$app->configure('custom_emails');
```

Then you can access like below:

```
config('filename.key_name');

#example
config('constants.email');
```

Comment: I think this is not relevant to the question... he is asking about caching the config, not where to get the config value...

Comment: I think it's relevant, although a further explanation is needed. Vasu should explain that you usually do not use artisan config:cache, but what he is explaning, and that is why it is not available out of the box. For me, this answer is the correct way to use configurations with Lumen.

Comment: This gives me `Target class [config] does not exist.`

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my issue with missing config:cache command.

Answer (score 1):

Lumen **no need** to `config:cache`.

You do not need to do anything after change ‍‍`.env`