# WAMP Laravel - Sending API requests from one local site to another mixes up environment variables

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, wamp

I am developing an API service that another site I've developed will be using. So locally when building and testing, obviously I want both local copies of the site to work. However, it seems to mix up the `environment` variables.

For example:

- `Site A` has `APP_URL=http://a.local`
- `Site B` has `APP_URL=http://b.local`
- I send a `GET` Request (using `Guzzle`) from `Site A` code to `http://b.local/test`
- The `/test` endpoing in `Site B` simply dumps out `dump(env('APP_URL'))`
- Result retrieved by `Site A` is `"http://a.local"`
- Expected result: `"http://b.local"`

So the code in `Site B` is running with environment variables loaded from `Site A`. This is an issue as `Site B` cannot access the correct database, it's trying to use the `Site A`'s database.

Is this an issue with my local setup (Win10 + WAMP), PHP settings, Laravel settings?

Comment: Any apache logs with errors? Or everything clear?

Comment: Nope, everything seems clear. Everything does work indeed, except using wrong environment variables :/

Comment: waht's about apache configs? I guess both sites have the same root path...

Comment: Yes, they have the same root path of `C:/wamp/www`. I don't know if there is any Apache config that would be related to PHP loading the environment variables?

Comment: so you have to specify different root path for each app, don't you?
E. g. `/wamp/www/app1` and `/wamp/www/app2`. You just load both sites with the same config. So you got actually one site)

Comment: @Tarasovych sorry I must've misunderstood you then. Yes, each site has it's own directory within the room I've specified, so one is loaded from `www/sitea/public` and the other from `www/siteb/public`

Comment: Did you tried to `SetEnv env_var_name env_var_value` in each `VHost`?

Comment: Hi! Can you provide, please, your web server configuration for both applications?

Comment: did you configure vhosts for b.local and a.local for different directories?

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök yes they are different apps and they run fine in the browser (completely different and correct), it's only when sending API requests that it seems to load wrong environemnt variables.

Comment: @Giedrius it seems like WAMP problem (especially Apache+PHP). In dev although a little bit slower I prefer not to use cache at all. So everything should be working fine if you run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`. Unfortunately, I guess it will not work in your case due to issues mentioned by @Daniel Protopopov. So instead of patching your app (which I find as Bad Practice), I would use [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead) since it provides environment as close as possible to production, and I haven't seen any problems with it (with cache enabled also).

Comment: did php artisan config:cache solved your problem

Comment: Can you please show where have you declared these variables ?

Comment: - If from terminal you do `curl http://b.local/test`, what do you get? 
- Does `Site A` have a `/test` endpoint as well? Are you sure that the endpoint called is correctly the one from `Site B`, with wrong environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encountered this issue, and it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19454). The resolution for it is to run **php artisan config:cache** in both projects to cache configuration from .env files or patch the code from [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8191#issuecomment-343081145).

Answer (score 0):

are you using artisan commands to run both projects with different ports ?

```
php artisan serve --port=8000

php artisan serve --port=8010
```

Comment: No, I don't use `php artisan serve` at all, all the local sites are managed by `WAMP` http://www.wampserver.com/en/ with different `VHosts` within `Apache`. Simply navigating the sites locally via browser works fine, it's only when one local site sends a request to another local site the environment does not load.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from  @Daniel Protopopov answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052556/6597265)  there is also another way, that is also works when both `Site A` and `Site B` are Lumen.

In short just rename your `DB_DATABASE` variable on each side to a different name. Then change the respective variable names in the respective `config/<configfilename>.php` files.

So that on `Site A` you would have `SITE_A_DB_DATABASE` in `.env` and matching `'database' => env('API_A_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),` line in `config/database.php`.

Then your `Site B` `SITE_B_DB_DATABASE` will not be overwritten due to variable names are different.

The same solution applies for any `.env` variables which names match.

Answer (score 0):

Because the command **php artisan config:cache** doesn't work here (closure needed in <strike>routes file</strike> config file)

```
LogicException  : Your configuration files are not serializable.
```

I add phpdotenv with composer :

```
composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

And at the begginning of the file "/bootstrap/app.php" (after "new Illuminate\Foundation\Application"), I add :

```
$app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__ . '/../', '.env');
    $dotenv->overload();
});
```

Maybe an alternative

Comment: As far as I know, `config:cache` does not cache routes, `route:cache` does. You must have something like a closure in your configuration files?

Comment: Yes @Giedrius, the `spatie/laravel-permission` package passes a `DateInterval` to the cache and I have not yet found how to solve the problem :
`'expiration_time' => \DateInterval::createFromDateString('24 hours'),`

Comment: I corrected my previous message ;) thanks @Giedrius

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a Lumen 8 API from within a Laravel 6 application using GuzzleHttp and the Laravel env is being inherited to Lumen, creating config file worked for me.

In bootstrap/app.php comment below lines to prevent loading current env values from Laravel

```
// (new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
//     dirname(__DIR__)
// ))->bootstrap();
```

In bootstrap/app.php add below line after $app has been created.

```
$app->configure('database');
```

Create config/database.php in lumen root folder. Return all env values needed for Lumen api in an array in the config file.

```
<?php
return [
'timezone' => 'UTC',
'default' => 'pdbmysql',
'connections' => [
    'pdbmysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'db2',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
    ],

],
];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set Environment variables in either the vhost config OR in an `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv APP_URL http://b.local
```